# Django: How to iterate over threaded comments inside of a template?

Tags: python, django

I've created a basic `BranchComment` model (ie: a threaded comment system) which has two possible foreign key attributes. One foreign key attribute is to the `PageInfo` model if it is a parent comment on someone's page (ie: a new post) and another foreign key attribute if the comment is a reply to another comment in which case the second foreign key is set to one of the actual BranchComment objects, indicating which comment it is a reply to. This way, comments can be infinitely chained to each other and/or used as a basic new post on a page.

Here's the model:

```
class BranchComment(models.Model):
    childtag = models.ForeignKey('self', related_name='child', null=True, blank=True)
    commentcontent = models.CharField(max_length=5000)
    parenttag = models.ForeignKey('PageInfo', related_name='parent', null=True, blank=True)
    commentdate = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    usercommenttag = models.ForeignKey(User, null=True, blank=True) #who posted the comment

     def __unicode__(self):
        return self.commentcontent
```

Obviously, you can get all the new posts on a page using the basic:

```
newposts = BranchComment.objects.filter(parenttag=PageInfo_instance)
```

Then I can loop over each parentcomment in the queryset and get the associated replies:

```
for post in newposts:
    replies = BranchComment.objects.filter(childtag=post).order_by('-commentdate')
```

So now my question is that I have a nice queryset of all the parentcomments (ie: original posts) and a nice queryset of ordered replies to each post, but how do I match them to one another in the template file? Thanks for any advice.

Answer (score 2):

```
for post in newposts:
    replies = BranchComment.objects.filter(childtag=post).order_by('-commentdate')
```

`replies` will be `BranchComment` objects with `childtag=post` of *last* `post` in `newposts`.

Some ideas:

```
replies = BranchComment.objects.filter(id__in=newposts).order_by('-commentdate')
```

In templates you can access related objects, for example `reply.childtag` or all children of `newpost` like this: `newpost.child`. And, for example, compare them:

```
{% if newpost == reply.childtag %}...{% endif %}
```

Could you provide more details, please? Thanks!

Comment: There isn't any more detail to provide haha, I just want to be able to show all the replies of comments and the replies to replies etc etc neatly on a template. What exactly does the BranchComment.objects.filter(id__in=newposts).order_by('-commentdate') do and where should it be inserted in the code?

Comment: I understand what you mean now. But my answer is useless then. You need something like `django-threadcomments`.

Comment: I have looked at that, but I would like to code my own so I better understand what is going on.